# Joining tables from two databases using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql, codeigniter

In order to write query in codeigniter you need to write something like `$this->db->query` or `$someDB->query`. But what if I want to join tables from two different databases?

I know that I can do it through pure php, using `mysqli_connect` and writing something like:

```
SELECT * FROM db1.table1 JOIN db2.table2
```

But is there a way to do it using codeigniter?

Comment: http://www.bsourcecode.com/codeigniter/codeigniter-join-query/

Comment: It turned that I don't need to join databases already. Thanks to everyone for some useful examples. Still, it would be interesting to learn how to do it, so I don't delete this topic for now.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can try to use the function I am using in a project I am working on right now... Please see the code below...

```
function join_table()
{
    $this->db->select(//column name, //column name, //column name);
    $this->db->from(//table1 name);
    $this->db->join(//table2 name, //table1 name.//column name = //table2 name.//column name');
    $this->db->where(//condition);
    return $this->db->get()->result();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Bryan, for the fast reply.

Comment: It's very useful, but there are examples of using join in single database. Forgive my stupidity, but I still don't get how to join tables from two different databases.

Comment: Don't think it would be right thing to change $this->db to $db1 and $db2 in these examples

Answer (score 0):

Use query method from CodeIgniter and pass any complex sql query trough:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM dbname1.table t1 JOIN db2.table t2 ON t2.column = t1.column");

foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
    print_r($row);
}
```

Comment: I suppose `$this->db` connects only db1. If I try to connect db2 through `$this->load->database('db2', true);` it returns: `pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR:  relation 'db2.table2' does not exist`

Comment: I mean, it returns error on query, not on db connection of course

Answer (score -1):

This simple join of student and teacher table with same column name  , Hope you will get it .

```
$this->db->select("s.*,t.*");
$this->db->from("student as s");
$this->db->join("teacher as t","s.student_id = t.student_id","both");
$result = $this->db->get()->result_array();
return $result;
```

also you want single row try row_array(); instead of result_array();

Comment: Thank you, that's great and very well explained, but I still need to join two different databases. Not two tables in one database.